# Difference between $("div") and $("</div>")?

Tags: jquery

I was asked in an interview, what's the difference between `$("div")` and `$("</div>")`?

```
console.log($("div"));
console.log($("</div>"));
```

Comment: You've got `$("")` in the question and `$("</div>")` in the example, which are we answering?

Comment: Basicaly - `$("")` : Create an empty jQuery object. `$('div')` : Select all divs in the DOM. `$("<div>)`: Create a `div` element and make it a jQuery object.

Comment: There's only one truth in development.  Developer trivia questions are ALWAYS the BEST way to decide whether to hire or fire!  ::totalLackOfSarcasm::

Answer (score 4):

`$("")`:

Returns an empty collection, i.e. a jQuery object with `length` of `0`.

`$("div")`:

Selects all the `div` elements in the document and returns a jQuery object.

`$("</div>")`:

The above code is supposed to *create* a `div` element but it fails and returns an empty collection, it should have been `$('<div/>')` or `$('<div></div>')`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to ask the difference between:

```
$("div")
```

This returns **all** div elements on the page.
... and ...

```
$("<div>")
```

This generates a **new** div element that can be manipulated and added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ contains all different use cases for the function `$`.

You're looking for the difference between

[jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

> Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML.

and

[jQuery( selector [, context ] )](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

> searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these elements: